# Mongo aggregation with relevance match multiple fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Working from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770673/sorting-by-relevance-with-mongodb) other question, I am trying to gather entries that contain a keyword based on a user's search input. This is for a client's site, the schema is set up like this:

```
{
    fid: Number, // unique id for client's internal purposes
    email: String,
    password: String, // hashed
    name: {
        first: String,
        last: String
    },
    group: {
        name: String,
        description: String,
        type: String
    },
    bio: {
        short: String,
        long: String
    }
}
```

And here is my query:

```
db.users.aggregate(
    [{
        $match: {
            $or: [
                {
                    'name.first': {
                        $regex: userInput,
                        $options: 'i'
                     }
                },
                {
                    'name.last': {
                        $regex: userInput,
                        $options: 'i'
                    }
                },
                {
                    'bio.short': {
                        $regex: userInput,
                        $options: 'i'
                    }
                },
                {
                    'bio.long': {
                        $regex: userInput,
                        $options: 'i'
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        { $unwind: { '$name.first', '$name.last', '$bio.short', '$bio.long' } },
        {
            $match: {
                $or: [
                    {
                        'name.first': {
                            $regex: userInput,
                            $options: 'i'
                         }
                    },
                    {
                        'name.last': {
                            $regex: userInput,
                            $options: 'i'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        'bio.short': {
                            $regex: userInput,
                            $options: 'i'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        'bio.long': {
                            $regex: userInput,
                            $options: 'i'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        { $group: { _id: '$fid', hitCount: { $sum: 1 } } },
        { $sort: { hitCount: -1 } }
    }]
);
```

For this type of query, I keep getting unexpected commas or end curly braces. I can't seem to find what I'm doing wrong (I've turned my mongodb.conf verbose logging up to 11). Where am I going wrong and am I even on the right path? I'd like to return each entry (object?) with all the info except the password field, how can I filter that out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using multiple `$or` clauses with [case-insensitive `$regex`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) isn't going to be very performant -- particularly if you have a sizeable amount of data to search.  MongoDB (as at 2.4) is not able to efficiently use an index for case-insensitive regex (standard indexes are case-sensitive), and matching anywhere within each field will be a costly comparison for large strings.  The `$or` clauses are executed independently, so you will ideally want to have an index on each field (to avoid a full collection scan) and the case-insensitive `$regex` comparison is still going to be a full index scan.

A much better approach for this use case would be using the [`text` indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/) available in MongoDB 2.4+.  Text indexes are case-insensitive, include [language-based word stemming](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/specify-language-for-text-index/), can include multiple text fields, and always return results in order ranked by relevance.  You can also [adjust the relative weights](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/control-results-of-text-search/) for the fields that are indexed.

It's worth noting that [stemming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) isn't the same as using a regex.  If you want to match words, stemming can be helpful in reducing to the common language root (i.e. "running" matches "run").

If you are matching names, you will probably want a fuzzy matching approach based on similarity or character transposition.  For a good writeup on several approaches to matching names, see [Efficient Techniques for Fuzzy and Partial matching in mongoDB](http://ilearnasigoalong.blogspot.com.au/2013/10/efficient-techniques-for-fuzzy-and.html).

Comment: I would also note that the text search feature was first introduced in MongoDB 2.4 and currently has to [be explicitly enabled](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-text-search/). In the upcoming MongoDB 2.6 release, text search will be enabled by default.  The MongoDB manual notes some [usage caveats](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/#storage-requirements-and-performance-costs) such as the larger size of `text` indexes and potential performance cost of stemming.